# A variation on Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

[Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) says that if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $\{a+bL\}_{L \in \mathbb{N}}$ contains infinitely many prime numbers.

I wonder if the following claim is true:

> If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $\{a+b^L\}_{L \in \mathbb{N}}$ contains infinitely many prime numbers.

Notice that if my claim is true, then Dirichlet's theorem is true.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** After receiving a few helpful comments, perhaps I should change my question to: Is there an additional condition that will make my claim true  (a condition on $a$ and $b$)?

Comment: No one knows if, for instance, there are infinitely many primes of the form $2^n+1$, though only a few are known.

Comment: Note:  you have to avoid silly counterexamples, like $1+3^n$ is always even.

Comment: We don't even know if there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, i.e. those of the form $2^p-1$ (it's easy to show you need prime $p$ here), which is about the simplest possible.

Comment: @lulu, thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Chappers, thanks for your comment. Please, do you claim that if $L$ is not prime then $a+b^L$ is not prime?

Comment: @lulu, what about $a^{L_1}+b^{L_2}$ (or $a^p+b^q$), where $L_1,L_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ ($p$ and $q$ are prime numbers)?

Comment: I mean that $2^{ab}-1= (2^a-1)(2^{a(b-1)}+2^{a(b-2)}+\dotsb+1)$.

Comment: Oh, I understand, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The unfortunate fact is that nobody knows much about anything more complicated than arithmetic progressions.  Even simple sounding questions like "are there infinitely many primes of the form $1+n^2$?" seem to be too difficult.

Comment: Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=4, b=n^4\,$ with $\,n \gt 1\,$, then $a+b^L$ is not a prime for any $L \ge 1\,$ by [Sophie Germain's](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Sophie_Germain_Identity):

$$a+b^L=4 + n^{4L}=(n^{2L}+2+2n^L)(n^{2L}+2-2n^L)$$

Comment: Nice, thank you. (I have added an edit to my question).

Comment: @user237522 Regarding the edit, an even weaker question is whether there exists *any* pair $\,a,b\,$ for which the proposition was proved. I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: ok.. thank you. Please, do you think that there is any hope to say something interesting about primes in $a^{L_1}+b^{L_2}$  (or $a^p+b^q$), where $L_1,L_2 \in \mathbb{N}$  ($p$ and $q$ are prime numbers)? Of course, $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be coprime.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative view that doesn't try to answer your question but merely points out some observations  you could make.

$\Bbb{Z}$ under the open set basis $U(a,b) = a + b\Bbb{N}$ forms a topological ring.

Fixing $a$ you can form a topology at least with $U(b) = a + b^{\Bbb{N}}$ since if $a + b^{\Bbb{N}} \cap a + c^{\Bbb{N}} \neq \varnothing$ say $x \in $ the intersection, then $a + b^n  = x = a + c^m$ or $b^n = c^m$.  There is a some work involved but you need to conclude that there is another basic open set $a + d^{\Bbb{N}}$ containing $x$ contained in the intersection.

Comment: Thank you, interesting. Is it possible to prove Dirichlet's theorem based on this idea?

Comment: @user237522 not sure.  Idk how Dirichlet's is proved.  But in both cases you have a topology on $\Bbb{Z}$.   It's only a  basic observation I'm afraid.  Note, that your case $a + b^{\Bbb{N}}$ may not be a *topological ring* basis, you'd have to prove that it is, but it's likely not because of addition not being continuous.  However, even though the ring operations aren't continuous, other things might be such as certain maps reminiscent of our basis set formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification/explanation.